# How To Integrate Woocommerce With A Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am having a hard time figuring out where to add the woocommerce loop in my woocommerce.php file.

Here is the page.php code,

```
    <?php
/*
Package: OnAir2
Description: Normal single page template with sidebar
Version: 0.0.0
Author: QantumThemes
Author URI: http://qantumthemes.com
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?> 
    <?php  
    get_template_part ('phpincludes/menu');
    get_template_part ('phpincludes/part-searchbar'); 
    ?>
    <div id="maincontent" class="qt-main">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <!-- ======================= HEADER SECTION ======================= -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'phpincludes/part-header-caption-page'); ?>
                <!-- ======================= CONTENT SECTION ======================= -->
                <div class="qt-container qt-spacer-l">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m12 l1 qt-pushpin-container">
                            <div class="qt-pushpin">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'phpincludes/sharepage' ); ?>
                            </div>
                             <hr class="qt-spacer-m">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 m12 l8">
                            <div class="qt-the-content">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ){  ?>
                                <hr class="qt-spacer-m">
                                <?php  comments_template(); ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <hr class="qt-spacer-l">
                        </div>
                        <div class="qt-sidebar col s12 m12 l3">
                            <?php get_template_part (  'phpincludes/sidebar' ); ?>
                            <hr class="qt-spacer-l">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php get_template_part ( 'phpincludes/part-sponsors' ); ?>
    </div><!-- .qt-main end -->
    <?php get_template_part ( 'phpincludes/footerwidgets' ); ?>
    <?php get_template_part (  'phpincludes/part-player-sidebar' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Where do I add the

```
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
```

I have tried just using the the get header and footer alone but the output was very very bad. Since the developer didn't make the theme woocommerce compatible I need to make it....

Answer (score 0):

Replace `the_content();` with `woocommerce_content();`. But still it won't adopt design. You manually have to make it woocommerce compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it completely joined the header and footer. the content section wont show up, here is the link to the shop:http://bluebridgetechnology.co.za/client/dexterity/shop/